# Elasticsearch Analysis

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How do I run this in chrome sense plugin:

```
 GET /_analyze?analyzer=standard?text='This is a test'
```

I am getting following error, not sure what is missing:

```
{
   "error": "ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[text is missing]",
   "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo in your request. The second '?' should be an '&'

```
GET /_analyze?analyzer=standard&text='This is a test'
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer, for troubleshooting this type of issue and to see what is being analyzed, use the analyze API in Elasticsearch 1x.  Here is an example:

```
GET dev_data/_analyze?field=MYFIELD_IND&text=Y 

{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "y",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 1,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

My problem was I was searching for an uppercase "Y", when it was an analyzed string, which by default is lowercase and my term search couldn't find it.  When I realized the case sensitive issue I reran the query with the lowercase "y" and it worked!